# How does execvp recognize its parameters?

Tags: python, exec

Suppose you wanted to ping your localhost in Python shell.

```
import os

os.execvp ("ping", ["ping","127.0.0.1"])
```

Where is "ping" taken from, how is it referenced?

The exec family of functions are system calls. System calls go straight into the kernel and typically perform a very specific service that only the kernel can do. So how does it know what "ping" is? Where is it taking ping from?

Comment: BQ: How can I know what parameters I can put?

Answer (score 0):

The "p" in the function name means that it searches the entries in `$PATH` for the command. Anything in any of those directories is a valid target.